# Chrome extension to read shopping cart

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How Can I read the cart products, from the chrome extension if the user is on the online stores like amazon or ebay then after reading moving the items to the another site.

Parsing the Whole Page For cart is a real pain for it. Any generic solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to have a [content-script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), it can read DOM structure.

Almost all modern e-commerce platforms support a structured markup language to describe products. 
I've worked with JS product parser. According to my experience, most popular are:

- [Schema.org](http://schema.org) ([Product example](http://schema.org/Product))
- [JSON-LD](https://json-ld.org/) ([Product example](https://jsonld.com/product/))

There are plenty modules for parsing such data available in NPM. For most e-commerce, it will be enough.

**Updated**. 

Ah, I checked the question again: you're asking about products which already were added to cart. But even in this case I still suggest you check page source for any structured data.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Are the extensions like universal cart and carribshopper working(parsing of the page).?

Comment: I am not sure how do they work, but there are few ways: popular e-comm websites may have public API or such extensions just have a custom parser for each popular site.